# Unable to read htaccess file - issue with Laravel or permissions?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have deployed Laravel to a Fedora 24 VPS but,

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

I have tried setting the web server as owner and adding the command line user to the web server group,

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/laravel
sudo usermod -aG apache fedora
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type d -exec chmod -c 755 {} \;
```

I have also tried making the command line user the owner and giving the command line user and the web server group permission,

```
sudo chown -R fedora:apache /var/www/laravel
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/laravel -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Finally I have just tried giving everything 777 permissions but to no avail.

I installed Laravel using Composer -  `sudo /usr/bin/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel /var/www/laravel` and this worked fine with no issues. I get no errors using `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` so could indicate an issue with my http.conf file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory /var/www/laravel>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone share some insight? I'm thinking there may be something wrong with the standard .htaccess but I'm at a loss to explain how.

### Environment:

- PHP 5.6.25
- Apache 2.4.23
- Laravel 5.3.9

Appreciate your help

Answer (score -2):

Try to change your virtualhost DocumentRoot to the root dir of the project, like:

```
/var/www/laravel
```

instead of

```
/var/www/laravel/public
```

and place there this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```